# TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'

Tags: python, typeerror

`TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'`

How do I fix this error? or what do I have to change around?
I'm a bit new to this and there's no other question?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

kivy.require("1.9.0")


class Jan(GridLayout, Screen):
    pass


class Feb(GridLayout, Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


WindowManager.add_widget(Jan(name='Jan'))
WindowManager.add_widget(Feb(name='Feb'))


class CalenderApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()


customWidget = CalenderApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    customWidget.run()
```

I believe the problem is located in the lines that includes `.add_widget`.

```
File "C:/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/DayMap.py", line 25, in <module>
    WindowManager.add_widget(Jan(name='Jan'))
TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'
```

Comment: you should create instance of `WindowManager` - ie. `my_manager = WindowManager()` - and then use `my_manager.add_widget(screen)`. Without instance it may expect `WindowManager.add_widget(instance_of_window_manager, screen)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in python, you should call a class function on object: `obj.function(params)`.
It is because the first parameter in the class function is `self`. And `obj` is passed as `self`.

But there is also another option: `class.function(object, parameters)`. In this case, `object` will be treated as `self`.

And this is how you called `add_widget` in your example. But since you did not pass `WindowManager` object, `Jan(name='Jan')` has been treated as `self`.

To fix it you can for example create WindowManager object and then call the method on this object:

```
widow_menage = WindowManager()    
widow_menage.add_widget(Jan(name='Jan'))
```